# Соединить два массива в специальном порядке [JS]

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно из этих двух массивов:

```
["Яблоко","Капуста"]
["Фрукт","Овощ"]
```

сделать:

```
["Яблоко","Фрукт","Капуста","Овощ"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const arr1 = ["Яблоко","Капуста"];
const arr2 = ["Фрукт","Овощ"];

const arr3 = arr1.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  acc.push(el, arr2[i]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = ["Яблоко","Капуста"];
let b = ["Фрукт","Овощ"];



for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ){
  a.push(b[i]);
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Результат отличается от требуемого)

Comment: Кажется, сортировка здесь не соответствует цели. Если я правильно понял, автору вопроса нужно просто «переплести» массивы. Чтобы за каждым элементом первого массива следовал элемент второго с тем же индексом.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Не понятно какой должен быть результат. Я думал функция sort сделает  по убыванию :(( сейчас уберу.

Comment: Да, в вопросе не совсем точно определены требования, но пример результата дан, его можно проанализировать.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty  не буду спорить как скажите

Comment: Ну, я не столько спорю, сколько пытаюсь сообща понять. В примере ведь после первого элемента первого массива идёт первый элемент второго, потом вторые элементы обоих массивов... У вас просто второй массив постепенно добавляется в конец первого.